# Gitlab installation issue on powerpc debian

Tags: debian, gitlab, powerpc

I would like to install gitlab on PowerPC mac mini running debian. I've tryed to install https://about.gitlab.com/downloads/#debian8 but it ends up with

```
E: Unable to locate package gitlab-ce
```

Anyone dealing with same issue? Every help is welcome.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Only AMD64 / X86_64 and raspberry-pi2 packages are available through apt, see https://packages.gitlab.com/gitlab/